# jquery easyui TreeGrid: How to make only Column Headers Bold

Tags: jquery, css, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am using jQuery EasyUI [TreeGrid](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/treegrid.php). How do i change the style for just the column headers?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdG7/3/). Can some one please show how to make just the headers `Bold`?

There is no help in documentation on how to style only headers. I am assuming it needs to be done by overwriting some css. I tried doing this by looking at the styles in Firebug

```
.datagrid-header {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

but it doesn't help as easyui overrides it somehow. I also tried several other rules but I am unable to figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the final fiddle? I am having a similar issue in changing datagrid's tr, th, td, cells, fonts, scrolling etc. Where did you add this customized css code? As far as I see it is, that you are accessing it via `http`, did you save it as a local css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that.

```
.datagrid-cell span {font-weight:bold;}
// or
.datagrid-row-over, .datagrid-header td.datagrid-header-over {font-weight:bold;}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working with just one problem. Now all headers are bold, but all values in first column are also bold! I am actually using a TreeGrid and not DataGrid. I just corrected that in the question. My Bad! How do i modify this to not make the entire first column bold?

Comment: Sorry didnt realize you had updated the answer. The First option is working with entire first column getting bold too along with the headers!  Second solution is not working at all.

Comment: Got it! changed it to .datagrid-header span {
 font-weight:bold;
}  and it worked! thanks!

Comment: If you already have customized css then best is to find it out your self with help of any browser source inspector by inspecting elemnt of subject. Look up unique class combination of this element and then create your own custom rule what ever you like to override.